# How to create a random spawnpoint off entities in Minecrat 1.17.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to create random spawn points on my Minecraft server, for instance, if a player die, the player would respawn at designated spots on the server, where I have dropped some tagged objects. But I don't seem to be getting the code right because I have tried some execute commands with a command block set to repeat, unconditional and redstone enabled.

**Code 1**:

```
execute as @a at @e[tag=Spawn] run spawnpoint @r ~ ~ ~
```

**Code 2**:

```
 execute at @e[tag=Spawn] run spawnpoint @r ~ ~ ~
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

Longer answer at the end.

If you don't care about efficiency (You have a low amount of players in the world or just aren't bothered by it) you can run the following command on a `Always active` `Repeat` `Unconditional` command block:

```
/execute as @a run execute at @e[sort=random,type=minecraft:armor_stand,tag=Spawn,limit=1] run spawnpoint @s ~ ~ ~
```

This command means: `For each player, do: Choose a random armor run Set the player's spawn to the armor's pos`

### Reason why your attempt didn't work

Here was your error in the command: When you use `execute as Someone` you can target this someone after the `run` using `@s` (self). In your atempt, you were disregarding the first @r by doing another @r, resulting in `For each player, Choose another random player`, making it possible for someone not being targeted.

#### How to use [@s] and [at @?]

##### How to use @s:

You can run the follwoing command:

```
/execute as @a run say @s
```

This translates to: `Execute the next command on every player individually, where @s will be replaced by whoever the player is.`

So this would go trough, lets say, you and me. First go trough me and change `@s` to `Bunny` and do `/say Bunny` as if I, the player, had typed that in chat. Then it would go trough you and do the same, but `@s` would be you.

##### How to use [at @someone]:

Now, note the second part `at @e[...]`. This will set the relative position of the command to the target's pos. So if we use `~ ~ ~`, we would be using the `@e[...]`'s coordinates on the next command. Inside the brackets, we have the `type`, `tag` and `sort` and `limit`. They just mean "Select at a random order, only one, with this tag and type".

##### Extra: Why is there two executes?

If you run `/execute as @a at @r`, this will do: `Choose a random player as a location and iterate on each player.`

If you run `/execute as @a run execute at @r`, this will do: `For each player, do: Choose a random player`

The difference is subtle, but on the first one, the player choosen as location is the same for everyone, but on the second one each player gets their own random location.

## Long answer

We can use scoreboards to detect when a player dies and use that as a trigger.

###### Scoreboard:

```
/scoreboard objectives add death deathCount
```

###### Commands:

First one in a `Always active` `Repeat` `Unconditional` and pointing to a second one `Always active` `Chain` `Unconditional`

```
/execute as @a[scores={death=1..}] run execute at @e[sort=random,type=minecraft:armor_stand,tag=Spawn] run spawnpoint @s ~ ~ ~
/execute as @a[scores={death=1..}] run scoreboard players set @s death 0
```

###### Translation:

```
For each player who has their death counter to at least one, At a random stand, set their spawn
For each player who has their death counter to at least one, set their score to 0
```

Comment: but mind if I ask about the version of minecraft you have tried the command on, because I'm running version 1.17.1 and the command is not doing anything.

Comment: 1.17.1 . Try running the commands individually on your chat. Create the score board, then do `/kill @s`, respawn, then run the first command, see what happens and what shows on chat. Then the last command. Then do /kill @s again and see if you spawned in the right place.

Comment: The second command works but not the first

Comment: Does an armorstand exsit with the tag `Spawn`? (Capital S btw)